# How to get consecutive numbers form user in a java program?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT.          
    int a,b,n;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      a=sc.nextInt();
     Scanner sv=new Scanner(System.in);
    b=sv.nextInt();
     Scanner st=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=st.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
       int c=0;
        c=2*c*b;
        int result=a+c;
         System.out.print(result+ " ");
      }

  }
}
```

I tried using scanner class but it is not executed by eclipse as it only shows sc,sv and st objects of scanner class is resource leaked and never closed.

Comment: Why are you using more than one scanner to the same stream?

Comment: a+2^(0)b,a+2^(0)b+2^(1)b,......,a+2^(0)b+2^(1)b+...+2^(n−1)b

Comment: I used scanner to get three variables from user and execute the above series.

Comment: Which tutorial made you think that is how you go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears you have some configs that keep your program from compiling and running based on the resource leaking (not an Eclipse user). Your code compiles and runs with Intellij on my machine so you have a few choices.

1. Change your configuration to ignore the warning/error. (not recommended)
2. Close the *one* `Scanner` you need. ([`scanner.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--)) You can get more than one value from the single scanner. So, ditch the other ones.

To accomplish (2) another way you could use try-with-resources block and it will be closed automatically at the end of the try.

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // put your code to get input here
} catch (IOException ioe) { ... }
```

In addition to the scanner issues you're asking about, you have a significant error in your code that will make it impossible to get any meaningful/accurate output. Consider...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        c = 2 * c * b;
        int result = a + c;
        System.out.print(result + " ");
    }
```

`c` is made anew on each loop and assigned a value of 0 and so `c = 2 * c * b;` will equal `0` *always*; and `a + c` will then *always* just equal `a`.

Answer (score -1):

Dont need to create a new Scanner Object...

just do:

```
int a, b, n;
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = sc.nextInt();


        b = sc.nextInt();

        n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int c = 0;
            c = 2 * c * b;
            final int result = a + c;
            System.out.print(result + " ");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was typing this out when @Xoce was posting his answer, so it's exactly the same as his :)

The only other thing that I'd like to add is that if you're using IntelliJ, try pressing control-alt-i to auto-indent your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT.
    int a,b,n;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    a=sc.nextInt();
    b=sc.nextInt();
    n=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int c=0;
        c=2*c*b;
        int result=a+c;
        System.out.print(result+ " ");
    }

}
```